# HP Hotkey UWP Service

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, hp-elitebook

As I am having this problem for the second time already, I want to post my own solution here so I can just look it up next time.

Im using a HP Eliteobook on which I did a clean Windows10 installation after receiving it. After that clean install I got this error described [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/HP-Hotkey-UWP-Service/td-p/6905324) which I solved back then. Now, after upgrading to Windows 10-1809 the same error pops up again:

> [Window name] HP Hotkey UWP Service
>
> Error: HP Software Framework is not installed in the system
>   Please download and install from the link -
>   ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-sofpaq/cmit/softpaq/CASLSetup.exe
>   Note: Restart system after installation

so, the link they provide is not even valid anymore, and I have absolutely no intention of re-installing HP bloatware anyway. There are some people in the HP forum thread I referenced above that report using other HP software like "HP Support Assistant" solved their problem. However I don't have all these available since I did a clean windows installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So before in- or uninstalling anything I checked the notebook's keyboard and tried all the F1-F12-keys (that without pressing Fn all have different functions - I believe those are what HP means by hotkeys). I checked if they do what they're supposed to do and I couldn't find any "hotkeys" that don't work.

If this is the case the solution is very simple:

1. open "Services"
2. find the entry "HP Hotkey UWP Service"
3. right click on it -> stop
4. right click on it -> properties -> set startup type to "disabled"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message when trying to up the brightness after uninstalling some bloatware. (and possibly, accidentally, one application that I actually needed)

What worked for me was going into the HP recovery manager and through 'reinstall drivers and/or applications' reinstalling 'HP hotkey support'.

If you don't have the recovery manager installed you might be able to find a download online.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same popup error when I wanted to turn up the brightness with the FN button + F9/F10.

The following worked for me:

1. Click on ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/softpaq/CASLSetup.exe (it should dowload it)
2. When it's done downloading run the .exe and it will prompt you with a wizard that you can follow.
3. When finished restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

CASLSetup.exe is an HP middleware software which enables the Functionality of many HP provided software. This is a genuine package from HP and not a bloatware. Please check the Digital Signature in the installer.

HP Hotkey UWP Service provides the functionality for Brightness +/- and Mic Mute from keyboard, which needs CASLSetup.exe for its functionality working.

If you really not want to install the 'HP Software Framework' software, then please update the BIOS to latest version, which will solve the pop-up.

Comment: This sounds interesting. The popup about CASLSetup.exe (appears, as you mention, e.g. when trying to change brightness over fn+f3) is not the popup I refer to in the question though (the contents are (almost?) identical, but mine showed every startup out of the blue). For now I simply don't use the button (not even on purpose, this is just not how I adjust my brightness xD) I might give the BIOS update a try, this seems like a clean solution.